# Как посчитать сумму тех значений в столбце, которые могут быть преобразованы в числа, игнорируя остальные?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть следующий DataFrame:

```
Column
22
38
26
35
35

54
2
27
14
4
58
20
39
14
55
2

31

35
34
15
28
8
38

19


40


66
28
42

21
18
14
40
27

3
19




18
7
21
49
29
65

21
28.май
```

Попытка `df['Column'].sum()` выдает ошибку:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: какую ошибку? непонятен контекст вопроса

Comment: все работает. только я неправильно указал. у меня где то Nan стоит, а где то даты..

Comment: хммм... а что вы ожидаете получить в качестве суммы дат???

Comment: да, извиняюсь. где то числа, где то даты, где то пустые. по-хорошему надо игнорировать и даты и пустые. оставлять только числа.

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев, вы можете [привести](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/610846/edit) пример ваших данных,  указать `error traceback` а также указать тип колонки `column` - `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: тип колонки object. с добавлением errors='coerce' ошибки больше нет. неправильно только считает).

Comment: а была ошибка: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'

Comment: у меня правильно считает... Вы уверены что считает не правильно?

Comment: да. все верно считает. спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [143]: df
Out[143]:
    Column
0       22
1       38
2       26
3       35
4       35
5       54
..     ...
37      21
38      49
39      29
40      65
41      21
42  28.май

[43 rows x 1 columns]

In [144]: df.dtypes
Out[144]:
Column    object
dtype: object

In [145]: pd.to_numeric(df['Column'], errors='coerce').sum()
Out[145]: 1181.0
```

**Предыдущий ответ:**

Скорее всего `column` - не численного типа:

работает для чисел:

```
In [116]: df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[1,2,np.nan,11,np.nan]})

In [117]: df
Out[117]:
   column
0     1.0
1     2.0
2     NaN
3    11.0
4     NaN

In [118]: df['column'].sum()
Out[118]: 14.0
```

не работает для строк:

```
In [119]: df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['1','2',np.nan,'11',np.nan]})

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
  column
0      1
1      2
2    NaN
3     11
4    NaN

In [121]: df['column'].sum()
...
skipped
...
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

**Решение:**

```
In [122]: pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce').sum()
Out[122]: 14.0
```